# iOS swift text background color uitextview

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uibackgroundcolor

I am trying to write code for a button that will change the background color of text selected by a user in a UITextView.

This is how I implemented the Bold formatting button:

```
@IBAction func boldButton() {
    textView.toggleBoldface(self)
}
```

But I don't know how to do something analogous for changing the background color of the selected text. 
Example code would be great!
Thx!

Comment: What does `toggleBoldface()` do?

Comment: It toggles the text that was selected to bold if it was not bold and vice versa. Very easy implementation.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the `tintColor` property of the `UITextView` to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and it changes the color of the text selector but it does not permanently change the background color of the text that was selected. This doesn't do what I was describing above. I would like something similar to highlighting text in iBooks, for example.

Comment: Does the user do this or this from your program

Comment: The user does it. It is a note-taking part of the app. The user types out notes and they will have the option to format the notes with **bold**, _italics_, underlining, or highlighting.

Comment: You can grab the selected text using the `selectedText` property, and reset the `UITextView`'s text with an attributed string on-the-fly based on that.

Comment: Thank you--I'm looking into it now and learning about attributed strings.